# PHP5.4+ Is there an alternative to explicitly creating dozens of objects to avoid warning?

Tags: php, stdclass

As of PHP5.4, PHP throws a warning when you try to use implicit casting as an object.

**Message: Creating default object from empty value**

Ordinarily, this can by prevented by explicitly declaring your variable type - e.g.

```
$thing = new stdClass();
```

But this gets tremendously annoying when you start dealing with libraries that convert objects into XML. So your previous code that said

```
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username = "myName";
```

becomes the bloated

```
$xml = new stdClass();
$xml->authentication = new StdClass();
$xml->authentication->identity = new stdClass();
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID = new stdClass();
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username = new stdClass();
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username = "myName";
```

But in instances like using XML, deep trees of nodes like this are very common.

Is there an alternative to explicitly declaring every level of every node in this way without fudging it by disabling warnings?

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
class DefaultObject
{
    function __get($key) {
        return $this->$key = new DefaultObject();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$xml = new DefaultObject();
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username = "myName"; // no warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
class ArrayTree
{
    private $nodes = array();

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if( !array_key_exists($name, $this->nodes) ) {
            $node = new ArrayTree();
            $this->nodes[$name] = $node;
            return $node;
        }
        return $this->nodes[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->nodes[$name] = $value;
    }

    // ...
}

$xml = new ArrayTree;
$xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username = 'myName';

var_dump($xml->authentication->identity->accountID->username);
```